# Why explicit call of base move constructor actually calls base copy constructor?

Tags: c++, move-constructor

I'm trying to call the base class move ctor explicitly through derived class move ctor but, **surprise!**, that actually calls the base class copy ctor NOT the base class move ctor.

I'm using `std::move()` function on an object to be sure that the derived move ctor is being invoked!

The code:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base(const Base& rhs){ cout << "base copy ctor" << endl; }
    Base(Base&& rhs){ cout << "base move ctor" << endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:

    Derived(Derived&& rhs) : Base(rhs) { cout << "derived move ctor"; }
    Derived(const Derived& rhs) : Base(rhs) { cout << "derived copy ctor" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Derived a;
    Derived y = std::move(a); // invoke move ctor
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

**PROGRAM OUTPUT:**

> base copy ctor
>
> derived move ctor

As you see, the base class move ctor is being forgotten, so how do I call it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the context of your `Derived` class the parameter `rhs` clearly has a name. Thus, it must be an lvalue, it can't be an rvalue. However, the `T&&` only binds to rvalues. If you want to call the base class's move constructor you need to use code like this:

```
Derived(Derived&& rhs): Base(std::move(rhs)) { std::cout << "derived move ctor"; }
```

This will call the move constructor of `Base` and move the `Base` portion of `rhs`. Since `Base` doesn't know anything about the `Derived` members, the `Base` move constructor won't move anything added by `Derived`.

Comment: and what if I would write in main function this:  Derived y = Derived(); and also forgot about std::move? I've tryed and in that case I got no program output, so what is then realy called?

Comment: @codekiddy: in the example `Derived y = Derived()` conceptually the move constructor is called: the object on the right can't be referred to, i.e. it isn't an lvalue. However, the move construction is probably elided by most compilers: the compiler is free to not use move (or copy) construction if it can construct the temporary object in the correct location directly, even if there would be side effects if the constructor wouldn't be elided (e.g.  output from the constructor or the destructor).

Comment: so to move base portion of rhs I'm forced to use Base(std::move(rhs)) in derived move ctor, is there any way to avoid std::move? thanks alot

Comment: @codekiddy: well, sure: you could have the derived constructors be implicitly generated or even make them explicitly have their default behavior: `Derived(Derived&&) = default;` However, the moment you explicitly forward the argument to the `Base()` constructor you need to use `std::move()` (or something equivalent).

Comment: OK, thans alot to you and others!

Answer (score 2):

A constructor, or any other function or method, with `&&` in its signature will only be eligible to be selected by the compiler if both these conditions hold:

- The datatype of the expression you are passing in is `T&&` or `T`. - i.e. `T&` won't be accepted
- *and* it actually has to be an rvalue - e.g. returned (by value `T` or by `T&&`) from a function.

`move(rhs)` satisfies both of these conditions. `rhs` is of the right type, but it actually has to be returned from a function (such as `move`) before it can be considered eligible to be passed into a function that requires an `&&`.

Answer (score 1):

If the base class move constructor were used, then the derived constructor could access a moved-from object.  That's dangerous, so it won't happen unless you explicitly tell the compiler that you're done using the object and it's safe to move.

Comment: It just being dangerous isn't anything special for the move-constructor. The reason is that the constructor of `Base` is called with an lvalue when writing `Base(rhs)` and lvalues never bind an rvalue reference: you have to make the lvalue look like an rvalue explicitly.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: It's classified as an lvalue, because it can be accessed later.

Comment: oh, you wanted to avoid the terms lvalue and rvalue? ... because this is the important difference between the two.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Not really that I wanted to avoid them, but you'd explained them so well, I just wanted to highlight why this is the *correct* behavior, from a type safety standpoint, not just "because the standard says so".